# Not able to add tags to the node drupal-7

Tags: tags, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I created 16 thousand nodes programmatically from drupal-6 to drupal-7 but not able to add taxonomy-term id to the node programmatically..

I added nid with their respective tid in taxonomy_index table.
Tags will be present in the views but it is not showing up inside the page also check the content-type and added all term-reference but no use...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are editing the database directly. This is not advised unless you really know what you are doing. I suggest that you programmatically add the terms to the nodes with the Drupal API. Something like:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76319/how-to-set-a-taxonomy-term-programmatically-for-a-node